# Xcode Server Bot integration fails to export archive: Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed."

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode-bots, xcode-server

```
2016-02-17 13:54:56.823 xcodebuild[26605:1155454] [MT] IDEBuildOperationQueueSetResourceManagement: Resetting max operation count to 6
    ** ARCHIVE SUCCEEDED **

     $ /usr/bin/xcrun xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-5041ec1e03066c77e1e1af601c03e78a/CardApp.xcarchive
-exportPath /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-5041ec1e03066c77e1e1af601c03e78a/ExportedProduct
-exportOptionsPlist /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-5041ec1e03066c77e1e1af601c03e78a/ExportOptions.plist
-IDEPostProgressNotifications=YES -DVTAllowServerCertificates=YES -DVTSigningCertificateSourceLogLevel=3 -DVTSigningCertificateManagerLogLevel=3 -DTDKProvisioningProfileExtraSearchPaths=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/ProvisioningProfiles
-configuration pre
     2016-02-17 13:54:57.249 xcodebuild[30225:1159538] [MT] IDEDistribution: -[IDEDistributionLogging
_createLoggingBundleAtPath:]: Created bundle at path '/var/folders/9h/ly8w3wnd6cn0t3y6kdhpnmtm000087/T/product_2016-02-17_13-54-57.249.xcdistributionlogs'.
    2016-02-17 13:54:57.265 xcodebuild[30225:1159540]  DVTSigningCertificateSource: Searching for signing identities in default keychain search list
    2016-02-17 13:54:57.287 xcodebuild[30225:1159540]  DVTSigningCertificateSource: Searching for signing identities in default keychain search list
    2016-02-17 13:54:57.318 xcodebuild[30225:1159540]  DVTSigningCertificateManager: __45-[DVTSigningCertificateManager forceFullSync]_block_invoke (0x7f8d42d4b4d0): Signing certificates = {(
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d52780; name='Mac Developer: OS X Server (XTP8DLJK38)', hash='504739CF310993D382EAC18B5FD6685F0EAED3E4', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.12'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d56ae0; name='iPhone Distribution: ***** Technology Co., Ltd. (KRQB3E5X27)', hash='C9D117064592B47FC805F05BE614EBF13DD4BCEE', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d5d9b0; name='iPhone Distribution: ***** Technology Co., Ltd.', hash='EE6AA59130285A6EF43F8BA29105571E7DE163B8', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d35b00; name='iPhone Developer: OS X Server (XTP8DLJK38)', hash='26D2BD0EB5741641B17A421FFB9EF6E33939A60D', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d5c670; name='Mac Developer: OS X Server (XTP8DLJK38)', hash='5028DB9F8F3740759C617188CEDD21890AAE10DF', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.12'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d59b90; name='iPhone Developer: OS X Server (XTP8DLJK38)', hash='7B76A1ABB3252977545BBFEA1A727CC80A53DCD0', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d56440; name='iPhone Distribution: ***** Technology Co., Ltd. (KRQB3E5X27)', hash='6C8E09899766E94DC872E9EAB77ED554F366549C', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4'>
    )},

     Signing Identity Certificates = {(
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d52780; name='Mac Developer: OS X Server (XTP8DLJK38)', hash='504739CF310993D382EAC18B5FD6685F0EAED3E4', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.12'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d56440; name='iPhone Distribution: ***** Technology Co., Ltd. (KRQB3E5X27)', hash='6C8E09899766E94DC872E9EAB77ED554F366549C', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d5d9b0; name='iPhone Distribution: ***** Technology Co., Ltd.', hash='EE6AA59130285A6EF43F8BA29105571E7DE163B8', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d35b00; name='iPhone Developer: OS X Server (XTP8DLJK38)', hash='26D2BD0EB5741641B17A421FFB9EF6E33939A60D', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d5c670; name='Mac Developer: OS X Server (XTP8DLJK38)', hash='5028DB9F8F3740759C617188CEDD21890AAE10DF', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.12'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d59b90; name='iPhone Developer: OS X Server (XTP8DLJK38)', hash='7B76A1ABB3252977545BBFEA1A727CC80A53DCD0', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.2'>,
        <DVTSigningCertificate: 0x7f8d42d56ae0; name='iPhone Distribution: ***** Technology Co., Ltd. (KRQB3E5X27)', hash='C9D117064592B47FC805F05BE614EBF13DD4BCEE', certificateKind='1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.4'>
    )}

2016-02-17 13:54:57.708 xcodebuild[30225:1159538] [MT] IDEDistribution:  Step failed: <IDEDistributionSigningAssetsStep: 0x7f8d42c7e060>: 

Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)"

error: exportArchive: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)
     Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEDistributionErrorDomain error 1.)"

    ** EXPORT FAILED **


===========================
```

This was working until a few days ago. Nothing had been modifyed. However the export fails！I have no ideas.

Comment: Xcode version 7.2.1.       Server version 5.0.15

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can make it a lot easier for others to answer your question, if you follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. Please make sure to edit your post accordingly, as a lack of quality in a question might result in others not bothering to answer

Comment: I have this same problem

Comment: @Siriss  reset certificate and delete  the  expired  Version of WWDR  https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/expiration/

Answer (score 3):

This issue occurs when the expired WWDR Intermediate certificate is present in both the System keychain and Login keychain within the Keychain Access application. To resolve the issue, first download and install the [renewed certificate](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer). Next, in the Keychain Access application, select the System keychain. Select 'Show Expired Certificates' in the View menu and then delete the expired version of the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority Intermediate certificate. Your certificates should now appear as valid in Keychain Access and be available to Xcode

Comment: Thanks , it saved me.

Comment: Cool. Worked for me!

Comment: Looked promising but didn't work for me unfortunately. Only had one such certificate in the System keychain with expiry 2023

Comment: @MaxMacLeod Hi Max, were you able to solve the problem, I am still not able to solve it. I too have certificate in System keychain with expiry in 2023..

Comment: Yes I recall that I deleted the team settings in Xcode Server. Then simply re-added them. Everything then worked perfectly.